# Parse & Compare Data using Coldfusion & MySQL

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

First, I'll explain what I need to do, then how I *think* I can achieve it.  My current plan seems very inefficient in theory, so my question is whether there is a better way of accomplishing it.

I have 2 Tables - lets call them 'Products' and 'Products_Temp', both are identical.  I need to download a large number of files (XML or XLS) which contain product details (stock, pricing etc) from suppliers.  These are then parsed into the Products_Temp table.  Right now, I plan to use CF Scheduled Tasks to handle the downloading, and Navicat to do the actual parsing - I'm happy enough this is adequate and efficient enough.

The next step is where I'm struggling - once the file has been downloaded and parsed, I need to look for any changes in the data.  This will be compared against the Products table.  If a change is found, then that row should be added or updated (if it should be removed, then I'll need to flag it rather than just delete it).  Once all the data has been compared, the products_temp table should be emptied.

I'm aware of methods to compare tables and sync them accordingly, however the issue I have is the fact I'll be handling multiple files from different sources.  I had considered using only the products table and append/update, but I'm unsure how I could manage the 'flag deleted' requirement.

Right now, the only way I *know* I can make it work is to loop through the products_temp table, do various cfquerys and delete the row once complete.  However, that seems incredibly inefficient, and given the fact we're likely to be dealing with hundreds of thousands of rows, unlikely to be effective if we update everything daily.

Any pointers or advice on a better route would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both responses have possibilities. Just to expand on your options a little ..

### Option #1

*IF* mySQL supports some sort of hashing,  *on a per row basis*, you could use a variation of [comodoro's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10698350/104223) to avoid hard deletes.

**Identify Changed**

To identify changes, do an inner join on the primary key and check the hash values. If they are different, the product was changed and should be updated:

```
    UPDATE Products p INNER JOIN Products_Temp tmp ON tmp.ProductID = p.ProductID
    SET    p.ProductName = tmp.ProductName
           , p.Stock = tmp.Stock
           , ...
           , p.DateLastChanged = now()
           , p.IsDiscontinued  = 0
    WHERE  tmp.TheRowHash <> p.TheRowHash
```

**Identify Deleted**

Use a simple outer join to identify records that do not exist in the temp table, and flag them as "deleted"

```
    UPDATE Products p LEFT JOIN Products_Temp tmp ON tmp.ProductID = p.ProductID
    SET    p.DateLastChanged = now()
           , p.IsDiscontinued = 1
    WHERE  tmp.ProductID IS NULL
```

**Identify New**

Finally, use a similar outer join to insert any "new" products.

```
    INSERT INTO Products ( ProductName, Stock, DateLastChanged, IsDiscontinued, .. )
    SELECT tmp.ProductName, tmp.Stock, now() AS DateLastChanged, 0 AS IsDiscontinued, ...
    FROM   Products_Temp tmp LEFT JOIN Products p ON tmp.ProductID = p.ProductID
    WHERE  p.ProductID IS NULL
```

### Option #2

If per row hashing is not feasible, an alternate approach is a variation of [Sharondio's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10703239/104223).

Add a "status" column to the temp table and flag all imported records as "new", "changed" or "unchanged" through a series of joins. (The default should be "changed").

**Identify UN-Changed**

First use an inner join, on all fields, to identify products that have NOT changed. (Note, if your table contains any nullable fields, remember to use something like `coalesce` Otherwise, the results may be skewed because `null` values are not equal to anything.

```
    UPDATE  Products_Temp tmp INNER JOIN Products p ON tmp.ProductID = p.ProductID
    SET     tmp.Status = 'Unchanged'
    WHERE   p.ProductName = tmp.ProductName
    AND     p.Stock = tmp.Stock
    ...
```

**Identify New**

Like before, use an outer join to identify "new" records.

```
    UPDATE  Products_Temp tmp LEFT JOIN Products p ON tmp.ProductID = p.ProductID
    SET     tmp.Status = 'New'
    WHERE   p.ProductID IS NULL
```

By process of elimination, all other records in the temp table are "changed". Once you have calculated the statuses, you can update the Products table:

```
    /*  update changed products */
    UPDATE Products p INNER JOIN Products_Temp tmp ON tmp.ProductID = p.ProductID
    SET    p.ProductName = tmp.ProductName
           , p.Stock = tmp.Stock
           , ...
           , p.DateLastChanged = now()
           , p.IsDiscontinued = 0
    WHERE  tmp.status = 'Changed'

    /*  insert new products */
    INSERT INTO Products ( ProductName, Stock, DateLastChanged, IsDiscontinued, .. )
    SELECT tmp.ProductName, tmp.Stock, now() AS DateLastChanged, 0 AS IsDiscontinued, ...
    FROM   Products_Temp tmp
    WHERE  tmp.Status = 'New'

    /* flag deleted records */
    UPDATE Products p LEFT JOIN Products_Temp tmp ON tmp.ProductID = p.ProductID
    SET    p.DateLastChanged = now()
           , p.IsDiscontinued = 1
    WHERE  tmp.ProductID IS NULL
```

Comment: thank you so much for that detailed reply.  You've given me plenty of options there!

Answer (score 2):

For finding the changes, I'd look at joins based on the fields you want to match on.  This can be slow, depending on the number of fields and whether or not they're indexed, but I'd still say it was faster than loops. Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT product_id
FROM Products
WHERE product_id NOT IN (
    SELECT T.product_id
    FROM Products_Temp T
    INNER JOIN PRODUCTS P
    ON (
        P.field1 = T.field1
        AND P.field2 = T.field2
        ...
    )
)
```

For the missing products to find the non-matches:

```
SELECT P.product_id
FROM Products P
LEFT OUTER JOIN Products_Temp T
ON (P.field1 = T.field1
    AND P.field2 = T.field2
    ...)
WHERE T.product_id IS NULL
```

Comment: +1 for JOINs. It is a lot more efficient than looping. As long as the tables share a PK/AK, you can easily identify new/modified or deleted records. I have used a similar approach many times (just with all inner/outer joins rather than subqueries).

Comment: @Leigh The first query I went with a sub-query because he wanted to find the non-matches, and to do that I had to join on the matches and then find the ones not in that recordset.  I'd love to see your approach for finding non-matches without a sub-query.

Comment: My take was he just wanted to update the changed records, rather than generate an audit log of the changes. In which case it is just a simple JOIN on the PK. Though you could do what you are describing with a JOIN. Just match on the PK, and test for non-equality of any of the other fields. Same concept, just approached from a different angle. However, you need to account for nullable fields with both approaches. Otherwise, you will get false positives when you compare the fields with `=`, `<>`, ... I got been bitten by that omission once ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had to solve a similar problem once, maybe the solution is applicable in your case (I do not know Coldfusion much). Why not (for each source) just delete everything from table Products corresponding to that source and replacing it with Products_Temp from the same source? It assumes you can make a unique field for each source. The SQL code would look something like:

```
DELETE FROM Products WHERE source_id = x;
INSERT INTO Products (field1, field2, ..., source_id) 
  SELECT field1, field2, ..., x FROM Products_Temp;
```

Also if the source doesn't change much, you can consider making a hash after its downloading and skipping the update if it did not change to save some database access.

Comment: Thanks @comodoro - thats one possibility, however (and this seems to be the main sticking point) I need to be able to flag anything in the products table that *isnt* in the products_temp table (this is to alert us when a product has been discontinued, for example).  Ideally, we would also want to update each record with a 'last change' flag too