# Returning new results only - better to store / filter data through SQL or ColdFusion?

Tags: sql, coldfusion, sql-server-2008-r2, coldfusion-10

I have a scheduled task which runs once daily that outputs data returned from a query into an excel file using cfspreadsheet. What I am trying to figure out is best method to take the data returned from query, store it in a "storage area", and use this stored data to do a compare on results from current data and results from previous data to display only NEW values from a column within the data on the report that gets generated the next day.

```
<cfset startDate = "#DateFormat(DateAdd('d',-1,Now()),'mm/dd/yyyy')# 00:00:00" />
<cfset endDate = "#DateFormat(DateAdd('d',-1,Now()),'mm/dd/yyyy')# 23:59:59" />

    SELECT DISTINCT TBLA.SerialID AS SerialID
        ,TBLA.BRND AS Model
        ,(SELECT TOP 1 E3.DNAME FROM TBLB E3 WHERE TBLA.USID = E3.USID AND E3.EOR = '3') AS EOR3DNAME
        ,(SELECT TOP 1 E3.VN FROM TBLB E3 WHERE TBLA.USID = E3.USID AND E3.EOR = '3') AS EOR3APPVN
        ,RELATION.GROUPID AS GroupID
        ,CONVERT(varchar, LOGDATETIME, 22) AS CheckIn
    FROM TBLA
         INNER JOIN RELATION ON TBLA.SerialID = RELATION.SerialID 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN TBLB E3 ON TBLA.USID = E3.USID
    WHERE TBLA.LOGDATETIME >= <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" value="#CreateODBCDateTime(beginDate)#" /> 
        AND TBLA.LOGDATETIME <= <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" value="#CreateODBCDateTime(endDate)#" />  
        AND TBLA.BRND LIKE (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%MER%" list="true" />)
    ORDER BY CheckIn ASC
```

One other tweak I'd like to do with my query is apply a condition for displaying the DISTINCT values based on the serial ID only and the most recent logdatetime (CheckIn) timestamp.

To reiterate, when process is doing compare from "storage area" and current data, to determine what data to display on new report, it compares all SerialIDs and checks it with current data to output only rows with new serialIDs or serialIDs not in the "storage area".

From what I've read, it's best to do this through DB through either stored procedure or setting up a VIEW in MSSQL as i'm working with thousands of data. However, I've also read I could use Solr / CFCollection. I'm leaned more towards relying on DB end then through application as there is more reliability on that end. Any suggestions or direction would be much appreciated.

I'm running MSSQL Server 2008 and CF10.

Edit: Here is what I am doing with updated code but having trouble, getting loop to work.

I basically manually created new table with serialIDs from previous data.

1. Table for new serialIDs 

   SELECT serialID as SID
   FROM blahList
2. Loop through #serialList# query so that I can exclude all data that matches serialIDs found on new report.

   Placeholder for Long Query above in my post is here with this condition added to the end for looping through serials
   WHERE tbla.SerialID NOT IN ("#SID#")
3. QUERY to insert new serialIDs found on query result to serialList
4. Perform query of query on "#longquery#" for writing new cfspreadsheet report

Comment: Do not have time to write up a full answer, but for db comparisons .. use the db :) Since you are running SQL Server, look into querying Excel files directly with [OpenDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179856.aspx), etcetera .. instead of `<cfspreadsheet action="read">`. It is a bit of [a pain to configure the first go round](http://www.maxxxie.net/2012/07/01/the-joys-of-importing-excel-data-into-sql-2008-r2/), but does work well.

Comment: Then you can query it like any other table. Depending on the complexity of what you are doing, you might prefer to import the data into a [temporary work table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698115/parse-compare-data-using-coldfusion-mysql/10716267#10716267). Side note, a much simpler way to do the date comparison above is use [`cf_sql_date` with the right filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13666883/date-comparison-in-ms-sql-2005/13687006#13687006).

Comment: It might be simpler to store the value of tbla.logdatetime when you run your report.  Then when you run it again, simply look for records more recent than the stored value.

Comment: Still kind of stuck on this. I went with creating an additional table approach to store the old values for SerialIDs, so that I can run a compare with my current data using cfloop and NOT IN to exclude, but for some reason it stops at the first row for looping and does not go through all rows for looping. What am I doing wrong? Will add revised code above.

Comment: Can you just write two queries for the old data and the new data? Is it just the date that differs? This should definitely be done in SQL and can likely just be done in a single cfquery tag.

Comment: *checks .. current data to output only rows with new serialIDs or serialIDs not in the "storage area"* Hm.. maybe I am misunderstanding the requirement. Why would "new" serial numbers be in the "current" db table, rather than in the spreadsheet? Initially this sounded like a typical "import data from spreadsheet process", in which case "new" items would be in the spreadsheet - not the db table. What am I missing?

Comment: Leigh et. al, I was able to complete a good portion of the issues I was having. Looking at my post, I now realize good old stackoverflow editor removed some of the code I added topost. What I did was create new table with id, insertdate, and logdatetime. I inserted all existing IDs to this new table. Then modified my dates, added first query to retrieve ids from new table, used `cfset oldIDs = ValueList(query.col)` to convert IDs to comma delimited, then in second query added condition to not include oldIDs using list=true for cfparam. Then writes to DB and spreadsheet if recordcount is GT 0

Comment: Leigh - To answer your last question, the original table itself is constantly hit with old and new serials differentiated by timestamp and other columns such as 3dname and appvn. What I needed to do at first was determine best method in storing data in a seperate area, which turned out to be another table. This new table holds 3 columns: serials, inserttime, and logdatetime. When I execute this task page containing code explained in my last comment, it compares new table with current table for any new serials in current table. If new serial found, write it to new table andlist on spreadsheet

Comment: Continuining from last post ....This spreadsheet is the report itself that I email out as notification. Process repeats everyday.

Comment: Now need to figure out two things. 1. Modify query to do distinct by serial column only and return the row of the serial with the most recent timestamp.  2. Most likely have to write a separate (query of query?) on the same page to report on serials that have logdatetime greater than x number of days based on logdatetime timestamp in new table. I'd probably have to do this second query after doing the new table update..