# Build struct and then populate with the values from query?

Tags: sql, struct, coldfusion, structure

I have task to update/insert some fields in two different tables. Before I run my update I have to grab values from my query and put them in structure where one of my values should be the key. My query looks like this:

```
<cfquery name="getRecords" datasource="test">
    Select 
         s.ID
         ,f.USER_ID
         ,s.USER_NUMBER
         ,s.STATUS
         ,f.DINING 
    From USERS s
         Left Outer Join FIELDS f ON s.ID = f.USER_ID   
</cfquery>
```

I need USER_NUMBER to use as a key in my structure and store all other values from the query above. I will use this structure to compare values from my other list and then build final list that I will use for update/insert. I tried something like the code below, but it did not work:

Here is a stand alone example using a manual query:

```
<cfset getRecords = queryNew("")>
<cfset queryAddColumn(getRecords, "ID", [1,2,3])>
<cfset queryAddColumn(getRecords, "USER_ID", ["userA","userB","userC"])>
<cfset queryAddColumn(getRecords, "STATUS", ["Active","Active","Active"])>
<cfset queryAddColumn(getRecords, "DINING", ["X","Y","Z"])>

<cfset myStruct = StructNew()>

<cfloop query="getRecords">
    <cfset myStruct = [key:#USER_NUMBER#{
                                         id:#ID#
                                         ,userid:##USER_ID
                                         ,status:#STATUS#
                                         ,dining:#DINING#
                                        }]>
</cfloop>
```

If anyone can help with this code please let me know. I usually use arrays but this time I have to use struct because of some other reasons. Thank you.

Comment: Phrases like "did not work" are very ambiguous. What is the actual result of the code above? What did you expect to happen instead?  *Before I run my update I have to grab values from my query and put them in structure* Just curious, but why is that needed? Reason for asking is it sounds like a possible over complication.

Comment: I just got an error on the screen. Why I want to put them in struct before I run update? I have to because values have to be compared with records from .csv file and then I have to check if they match, if they do I create a list for values that match and later use that list for update/insert.

Comment: I suggest a totally different approach.  Start by loading the csv file into a separate table.  Whether this is done with or without ColdFusion doesn't matter.  Then use a combination of staging tables and sql queries to identify what data has to be written, and then write the necessary data.

Comment: Please update the question to include the actual error message. Why not just load the csv into a staging table? Then you can validate, compare and update with SQL statements rather than a bunch of loops and CF code (overly complex). Data manipulation is really what database are designed for - not CF.  Which dbms are you using?  Take a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698115/parse-compare-data-using-coldfusion-mysql/10716267#10716267) for some general ideas on identifying new and changed records.

Comment: @Leigh and Dan Bracuk I know that would be the best way but in my situation we are not allowed to create any kind of tables in data base. That's why I have to approach this way, makes everything more complicated and not that efficient. I'm not getting any error on my screen after I did last update for CF11. Makes my work more complicated. If any of you can help me with the struct above I would appreciate that. Thank you.

Comment: (Edit) @user3023588 - Not even temp tables? Ugh.  What do you mean "update for CF11"? I see some syntax errors in your code, such as using `:` rather than `=`.  However, it is hard to offer more advice without an an error message. Start by putting together an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we can run independently.  Start with a manual query, then add the problem code.  [Starter example on trycf.com](http://trycf.com/gist/3371caa6654fb4e8f837249934afb50d/acf2016?theme=monokai)

Comment: I have created example in editor. You can take a look now. Also this what i used gave me USER_ID to be my key what i want but only problem is I do not know how to get more than one value stored after that. I only have DINING value for now but I have to put USER_NUMBER and STATUS in the struct too.

Comment: Thanks. Hope you do not mind, but I added in the manual query as an example of what I meant by an MCVE :) Anyone can now copy the code above, paste it into an editor and run it in their environment, without needing a database. (Though I suspect Jedihomer Townend provided the solution already, just thought this might help with future questions)

Answer (score 3):

I believe you just need to move your key up a level so that the loop doesn't overwrite the values.  so try something like:

```
<cfset myStruct = StructNew()>

<cfloop query="getRecords">
    <cfset myStruct[getRecords.USER_ID] = {
        id:getRecords.ID,
        userid:getRecords.USER_ID,
        status:getRecords.STATUS,
        dining:getRecords.DINING
    }>
</cfloop>
```

Then to access the variables you can use something like:

```
<cfoutput>#htmlEditFormat(myStruct[1].dining)#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: ... where `1` represents the key or getRecords.USER_ID value.